# How can I do Python interpolation with 2D data?

Tags: python, interpolation

I'm new to Python, and I have a simple interpolation example that I'd like to solve using 'interpn'.

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,4)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,5)

A = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))

for i in range (1,len(x)):
    for j in range (1,len(y)):
        A[i,j] = np.sin(x[i] ** 2 + y[j] ** 2)

x1 = np.linspace(0,1,10)
y1 = np.linspace(-1,1,20)

xi,yi = np.meshgrid(x,y)
x1i,y1i = np.meshgrid(x1,y1)



int_A = interpn(xi,yi,A,x1i,y1i)
```

For this, I end up getting the value error "interpn only understands the methods 'linear', 'nearest', and 'splinef2d'".
So when I have all input data to be 2D arrays, how do I use the 'interpn' function for interpolation, or any other Python interpolation function in that case? I'm also interested in doing 3D interpolation with all input data and function values being 3D arrays.
Can someone please help me with these issues?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html?

This should allow you to put in a 2D grid as an input.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I did.  " int_A_3 = griddata((xi, yi), A, (x1i, y1i),method='linear') ".  This is what I wrote for the 'griddata' function, but I get the value error 'different number of values and points'. I'm not sure if it's the way I'm inserting the inputs in to this command, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From scipy api:

```
scipy.interpolate.interpn(points, values, xi, method='linear', bounds_error=True, fill_value=nan)

points : tuple of ndarray of float, with shapes (m1, ), …, (mn, )
The points defining the regular grid in n dimensions.

values : array_like, shape (m1, …, mn, …)
The data on the regular grid in n dimensions.

xi : ndarray of shape (…, ndim)
The coordinates to sample the gridded data at
```

I believe you need to package your points further into tuples. Try 
`int_A = interpn((xi,yi),A,(x1i,y1i))`

Same when you do 3D, just add zi and z1i to the tuples.

Comment: Thank you! I actually have tried this already, and the value error was 'The points in dimension 0 must be 1-dimensional'. I read about these types of value errors to see how I can adjust the command to overcome it, but still no luck

Comment: I see. Well, you definitely need to be passing the arguments as tuples, that's the cause of the error about the method. The underlying issue then I think is because your ranges are starting at 1. Try starting them at zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! I tried it now, but the error message is still the same. I actually also tried to convert these 2D arrays in to tuples, using the command line "t_xi = tuple(map(tuple, xi)) " ,for all xi,yi, x1i, y1i in a similar way. Then  tried "int_A = interpn((t_xi, t_yi),A,(t_x1i, t_y1i))", but it gives the same error.